# J-unit Testing - Writing Test Case of a Class which is extended by dialogue or Asynctask?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, testcase

I am new to testing phase ,I'd like to write test case of a class which is extended by dialogue or Asynctask ,but i am not able to access the stuff of dialogue class in my test case .
rather i have successfully done this with Activity (using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2).
Any help will be more than appreciation.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your testcase has to extend `AndroidTestCase`

```
public class MyTest extends AndroidTestCase{

    public void test(){
       //access dialog here 
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah morad thanks for your reply but extending AndroidTestCase I am not able to access the content of dialogue class. Do you have any exp?